# Caching internal bean calls

Tags: java, spring, caching

I have the similar problem as described in this thread: http://forum.spring.io/forum/attic/spring-modules/22590-can-t-cache-result-of-inner-method-call

But I don't like to decompose my bean in a chain just for caching. In my case I need to create a chain of three fake beans just for caching!

I understand that the caching proxy just delegates all calls to the original bean, so inner calls cannot be intercepted. I understand this in case of java config -- I've just created my bean with the 'new' keyword. But why I got the same behavior on xml config? I expect that Spring can extend my class with its constructors and create an instance of a new class. So all inner calls will be also go through the caching layer due to polymorphism.

Is there any way to force inheritance but not delegation to the original bean?

Thanks,
  Alexey

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the [chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) in the reference. It says that "Spring AOP is proxy-based." There is a way to access reference to a real proxy: `AopContext.currentProxy())` to call it instead of "this" bean.